# Haxe/Bash: Calling the Bash `read` builtin from a Bash script run from the haxe `-cmd` option

Tags: bash, scripting, haxe

I'm having trouble successfully calling `read` from a script called by Haxe's `-cmd` option.

I'm scripting a testing framework for Haxe and want to be able to test multiple targets from one command. The idea is to clear to compile to a target, clear the terminal, run the test/s (and display results), wait for a key-press, clear results, compile to another target, clear, run, wait, clear, etc.

I've run into a problem with the 'waiting for a key press' part. I'm using the Bash `read` builtin, and if I run the script directly from the terminal it works fine. But when I call the script using Haxe's `-cmd` option, `read` doesn't print it's prompt or continue after a key press.

[image: screenshot of the terminal after failure]

I've tried writing the bash script as a series of `-cmd` commands, but it runs through sh instead of bash and I'm given the errors "/bin/sh: 1: read: Illegal option -n" "Error: Command failed with error 2".

**test.hxml** - called manually (`haxe test.hxml`)

```sh
-main   Main
-cp     ../hxdf/

################################
--each

-neko   ./neko/run.n
-cmd    bash test.neko.sh

#-------------------------------
#--next

#-cpp    ./cpp/
#-cmd    bash test.cpp.sh
```

**test.neko.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

clear

printf "compiled to neko - running\n\n"

neko ./neko/run.n

printf "\n"
read -n1 -s -r -p "press any key to continue"

clear
```

The `read` builtin behaves differently because it's called by the Haxe compiler. Would there maybe be a way I can move it to a different process while still having it effect the terminal I launched the Haxe compiler from?

**EDIT:**
The `/bin/sh` error only occurs when I have *test.hxml* set to this:

```
-main   Main
-cp     ../hxdf/

################################
--each

-neko   ./neko/run.n
-cmd    clear
-cmd    printf "compiled to neko - running\n\n"
-cmd    neko ./neko/run.n
-cmd    printf "\n"
-cmd    read -n1 -s -r -p "press any key to continue"
-cmd    clear

#-------------------------------
#--next

#-cpp    ./cpp/
#-cmd    bash test.cpp.sh
```

Comment: Your shell interpreter is set incorrectly, use `#!/bin/bash`. The error looks like the `read` command on the POSIX `sh` shell does not accept that argument. Invoke the bash shell as above

Comment: Tried it, no change. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Which system are you running this on? Are you execute `read` with the required arguments from the command line and see if its supported?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Native Terminal. Yes, executing `read -n1 -s -r -p "press any key to continue"` works as expected.

Comment: But as I said before, look at the error string that says the interpreter as `/bin/sh` which is incorrect, I can't comment for `haxe`, but somehow your invocation is not calling the `bash` shell

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: read: Illegal option -n" "Error: Command failed with error 2` that's pretty clear.... Can you post the output of `whereis bash`, `stat /bin/bash`, `stat /bin/sh`, `bash --version`, `/bin/sh --version`. Just limit yourself to the POSIX compliant [read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) or try `dd if=/dev/stdin of=/dev/stdout bs=1 count=1`

Comment: I've edited my question. The `/bin/sh` error only comes up if I'm trying to call `read` directly from the Haxe `-cmd` option - I added it because it seemed like I needed to put something in about what I've already tried, but I don't think it's related.

Comment: If nothing works then I'll use the POSIX sh `read` and just ask the user to press enter otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The `-cmd` flag doesn't work perfectly all the time. Apparently some shell features don't work with it (e.g. pipe to file "`>`", or this [issue](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/6726))

I suggest you write a Haxe script to run your test, example untested code:

```
Sys.command('haxe test-neko.hxml');
Sys.getChar();
Sys.command('haxe test-cpp.hxml');
Sys.getChar();
// etc
```

Comment: Looks like that might be the best choice. I wanted to stay away from it because of the needing a binary and all but I can make that easier to get around...

There's also some haxe scripters ([haxex](https://gist.github.com/jasononeil/5432759) and [ihx](https://lib.haxe.org/p/ihx/)) I could look into maybe.

Comment: You don't need a binary, you can use the built-in interpreter (`haxe --run Main [args...]`).

Comment: or run it using the buildin interpreter `haxe -main MyScript --interp`